# gerund and infinitive difference

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive, infinitive-clauses

> I regret being late

vs

> I regret to be late.

what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences???

Comment: The difference is the second is ***invalid*** (idiomatically, at least; I'm not sure which if any actual grammatical ***rule*** it breaks). You can follow ***I regret*** with an infinitive in constructions like *I regret **to inform you** [of some bad news]*, but this doesn't work with verb phrases like *I regret **to be late**, I regret **to see you**, I regret **to leave now*** (all of which are "invalid").

Comment: The difference between 1: *I regret **to inform** you she's dead* and 2: *I regret **informing** you she's dead* is that the speaker in #1 is *currently* giving the other person the bad news (and is sorry he must do this), whereas in #2 the speaker gave that bad news sometime ***earlier***, and is now expressing regret for having done so (he ***now*** wishes he hadn't told the other person before, equivalent to *I regret **having informed you...***).